# Changing View Controller After Google Place Picker

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps-api-3, gmsplacepicker

Does anyone know how to go to a different view controller after selecting a place in Google Place Picker other than the one that called the place picker?

Comment: You can use ''mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker)" delegate function, This function event will call while tap google marker

Answer (score 0):

according to google place picker [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker)

```
@IBAction func pickPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
  let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

  placePicker.pickPlace(callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
      print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return
    }

    if let place = place {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         //code to push or present a viewController
      }
    } else {
      print("No place selected")
      return
    }

    print("Place name \(place.name)")
    print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
  })
}
```

Hope this helps